# Pesquisas com usuários

Tags: debate, estudo-científico

Não é incomum que pessoas envolvidas em trabalhos acadêmicos entrem em contato conosco pedindo dados para serem usados nos estudos que estão desenvolvendo.

O princípio do Stack Exchange é compartilhar conhecimento. Então, mesmo que já existam dados públicos, (vide [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) e [data dumps](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange)), sempre que possível nós tentamos dar apoio aos pesquisadores. Claro que **sem nunca compartilhar dados pessoais ou de contato**.

Algumas dessas pesquisas também dependem de questionários com os usuários e, nesses casos, fica a critério da comunidade se ela quer participar ou não.

Essa semana chegou ao meu conhecimento um estudo sobre a participação de usuários 
do SOpt e SOen, que gostaria de convidar vocês a preencher um questionário.

A pergunta é: *vocês querem (ou se importam) de terem esses estudos divulgados aqui*?

Comment: Desde que o meta não fique todo infestado de pesquisas, talvez seja uma interessante experiência, apesar de que eu não tenho interesse em participar de nenhuma, mas não vejo mal de tê-las de forma controlada para outros que queiram participar.

Comment: **[...]sem nunca compartilhar dados pessoais ou de contato.** e **Algumas dessas pesquisas também dependem de questionários com os usuários[...]**... A ideia seria postar no meta o questionário e quem quiser responde, a SE mandará um e-mail com a pesquisa ou passará o nosso e-mail aos pesquisadores? Ficou meio "obscuro" essa parte. xD

Comment: @Randrade Os pesquisadores divulgariam os questionários no Meta. Quase sempre são links para um Google Form. Esses dados nunca passam pela nossa mão

Comment: Se alguém responder sua pesquisa dizendo que não gosta de responder pesquisas ela estará se contradizendo.  Acho que temos um xeque-mate.

Comment: @carla Foi tudo um plano meu :D

Comment: se o responsável da pesquisa der feedback depois, mostrar os resultados, etc, tenho interesse.

Comment: Sim! [Eu mesmo já fiz isso (de forma sutil)](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2403/h%C3%A1-alguma-%C3%A1rea-aqui-no-so-pt-para-pesquisas-acad%C3%AAmicas-cientificas/2410#comment-8087), e até já criei [está proposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2403/2998).

Answer (score 18):

Sim, claro, porque não?

Ainda que podemos ter um [Schrödinger's cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger's_cat) aqui, mas o risco é baixo :)

Comment: Não entendi a piada, quem seria o gato nesse contexto?

Comment: @bfavaretto a pesquisa, depois de postar pode ser que a gente não queira mais :)

Comment: Enquanto a pesquisa não for divulgada, e não soubermos da recepção dela, ela se encontra num estado quântico sobreposto de aceitação e não-aceitação :D

Comment: SIM. Que venham os questionários!

Comment: Sim. No entanto, depois, deveria-mos de ter acesso aos resultados do estudo.

Comment: @ramaral eu posso conversar com os eventuais pesquisadores sobre o assunto, mas por conta das restrições normais sobre a publicação de trabalhos acadêmicos, é difícil tornar isso uma obrigação ou requisição

Comment: Pelo gato de  Schrödinger, eu voto sim!

Answer (score 14):

Sim, claro, porque não? Desde que seja em Português! ;)

Comment: Do Brasil ou de Portugal? :P

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio desde que seja português já está de bom tamanho ;)

Comment: Acredito que de Angola seja melhor.... nem um, nem outro...

Answer (score 8):

Abrir espaços para os usuários responderem "surveys" pode ser aceitável mas eu não participaria de nenhum mesmo que pagasse.

No entanto, não sou contra quem quer participar e, não poluindo o ambiente com "annoying surveys", não tem problema.

Answer (score 7):

Não vejo problemas em ter algo desse tipo, desde que seja algo transparente.

Por exemplo, o fato de eu aceitar participar de uma pesquisa, não significa que desejo participar de outras, ou vice-versa.

Deixando claro essas informações ao escolher participar ou não, eu não vejo problemas.

Answer (score 4):

Todo grande sistema tem um grande volume de dados, e dados hoje tem muito valor.

Se esse canal de distribuição fosse voltado apenas para isso, acredito que seria sim positivo.

Ao mesmo tempo, o usuário "comum" não tem interesse nisso, nem em ver isso. Deve ser um dado acessível a partir de algum nível ou apenas através do meta mesmo.

Answer (score 3):

Contribuir é sempre importante.

Answer (score 2):

Sim claro! Participação e um principio da comunidade opensource, disponibilizando a pesquisa aqui nós temos acesso ao estudo e ao background do pesquisador, tem tanto material de qualidade hoje estocado em bibliotecas de universidades e invisiveis ao nossos olhos. Disponibilizando aqui o formulario com as perguntas e o relatorio final vai ser de grande ajuda a futuros pesquisadores e criativos.

Answer (score 1):

Acho interessante, desde que nos sejam divulgados os resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Falando de Brasil, acho que conseguir respostas de qualidade, um grande problema a pesquisadores, então se for possível melhorar um pouquinho que seja, vamos fazer!