# Questionário/Survey usuários StackOverfow em português e inglês. [Resultado e Artigo Publicado]

Tags: debate, estudo-científico

Olá!

Conversei com Gabe, e [ele me deu autorização para convidar vocês](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5724) para responder um questionário de uma pesquisa acadêmica que estou fazendo parte. Eu divulgarei o resultado assim que possível. Mas deixa eu me apresentar =) :

Meu nome é Weslley Torres. Eu estudei na UFPE, onde eu consegui meu mestrado em Ciência da Computação, e agora estou fazendo doutorado na universidade de Eindhoven (Holanda). Eu estou fazendo parte de uma equipe de pesquisadores em Ciência da Computação das universidades de Vrije Universiteit Brussel, Bélgica (Angela Lozano `alozanor@vub.ac.be`), Universidad de Guayaquil, Equador (Miguel Botto Tobar `miguel.bottot@ug.edu.ec`) e Technische Universiteit Eindhoven, Holanda (Weslley Torres[1] `w.silva.torres@tue.nl` e Alexander Serebrenik[2] `a.serebrenik@tue.nl`.)

O propósito deste estudo é nos ajudar a entender as motivações por trás do uso do Stack Overflow (SO) e até que ponto o uso dessa ferramenta pode contribuir para a melhoria de algumas habilidades dos usuários. Nós estamos particularmente interessados em desenvolvedores brasileiros que utilizam as duas versões do Stack Overflow (em português e inglês).

Para nos ajudar, vocês só precisam responder a um questionário. A participação é voluntária e não há risco em participar. Ele não coleta informações que possam lhe identificar e não iremos compartilhar ou vender qualquer resposta individual. Este questionário leva em torno de 10 minutos para completar.

Ao finalizar e submeter o questionário, você está concordando em participar desse estudo. Nós também iremos sortear um Giftcard da Saraiva, no valor de R$ 50,00, entre aqueles que completarem e informarem o e-mail ao final do questionário.

Se vocês tiverem qualquer dúvida, por favor, entrem em contato conosco, podendo ser tanto em inglês quanto em português.

Sua participação é muito importante para nós.

Aqueles que tiverem interesse, por favor, envie um e-mail para `w.silva.torres@tue.nl`, que eu encaminharei o link do questionário.

Usuários aptos para responder este questionário são:

**- Usuários que usam as duas versões do StackOverflow.**

**- Não tenham respondido este questionário anteriormente.**

**Questionário será fechado em 17/03/17.**

Muito obrigado pela atenção.

[1] https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=iNNDS7IAAAAJ&hl

[2] http://www.win.tue.nl/~aserebre/

**Atualização:**

Pessoal, segue o link de quem quiser conferir a versão preprint do artigo que vai ser publicado em ICGSE 2018 (maio):
http://www.win.tue.nl/~aserebre/ICGSE2018.pdf

Muito obrigado a todos que participaram.

Comment: O meu está respondido, espero que seja útil para vocês.

Comment: Existe algum motivo para não linkar diretamente o questionário? O e-mail é necessário?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento fazer um filtro de quem pode responder.

Comment: @bigown entendo, só acho meio "burocrático", apesar que tem razão, quem tem algum tempo/paciência para responder terá para enviar um e-mail. o/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, você tem alguma sugestão? Concordo que é o meio burocrático, mas não conseguimos pensar em outra forma =/. Eu procuro responder os e-mails o mais rápido possível. =)

Comment: @WeslleyTorres não foi bem o que eu quis dizer, eu entendo que deve haver motivações além da minha compreensão, por exemplo, o formulário é gerado por alguma "ferramenta" que necessita de um email para vincular, então não tem como postar postar o link do formulário diretamente (é apenas suposição), no entanto se tivesse como cadastrar o email no momento de preencher a o questionário (com validação através do recebimento na inbox) faria ser um pouco menos burocrático e assim despertaria mais o interesse das pessoas em participar. Mas creio ser  uma limitação técnica :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Então, é como o bigown respondeu lá em cima, é só para filtrar quem pode responder o questionário mesmo. E o questionário, é um formulário simples do google. Ahh e estou esperando o seu contato para eu enviar o link do questionário =)...

Comment: @WeslleyTorres apesar de colaborar no site meu conhecimento é limitado, estou enviando a solicitação de qualquer forma :)

Comment: Você vai divulgar algo aqui posteriormente (assim que a pesquisa terminar)?

Comment: Só uma dúvida, como você vai ter certeza de quem estiver enviando email para você atende os criterios?

Comment: @diegofm você vai indicar seus 2 perfis, ele vê se você tem atuação nos 2 sites. Se tem algum critério mais específico só ele pode responder, mas isto é o básico.

Comment: Eu recebi por e-mail e respondi àquele questionário que era válido até 10 de fevereiro de 2017. Esse novo questionário é igual ao anterior ou o anterior era uma espécie de beta ou coisa semelhante?

Comment: @diegofm eu fiz o questionário, não é bem uma avaliação pessoal, é mais sobre o SO-EN e o SO-PT, entender os critérios das comunidades, eu também achei que não ficou bem explicado aqui, não é sobre nossas capacidades, seria mais algo como *"o que o SO representa para nós?"*

Comment: @VictorStafusa , é o "mesmo" que você respondeu. Na verdade é uma cópia pq já estamos processando aqueles resultados...Aí como você já respondeu o primeiro, você não pode responder esse. =)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento , sim vamos divulgar todos os resultados. Não as respostas individuais mas a estatística das respostas. Infelizmente eu não tenho como dizer uma data específica, mas espero que logo. =)

Comment: Na minha pouca experiência com pesquisas, já percebi que as pessoas não respondem pesquisas. Colocar uma etapa a mais de burocracia (mandar um email para receber o formulário) acho que vai diminuir ainda mais o numero de respondedores. Pensei a mesma coisa que o Guilherme, um formulário com campo 'email' obrigatório me parece fazer o mesmo serviço e de maneira muito mais direta.

Comment: @carla o problema neste caso é um link para o questionário ser repassado indevidamente a alguém que não atenda os requisitos e a pessoa investir um tempo respondendo só para ter o questionado descartado. Apesar de improvável, acho mais danoso do que a "fricção" inicial. A fricção cria uma dificuldade em obter candidatos, a não fricção traz o ônus da comunidade para quem responder de boa vontade sem ter sido informado ou atentado aos requisitos que são avaliados de antemão no email.

Comment: @Bacco mas ae só justifica se o Weslley pegar o seu endereço de e-mail quando recebe o pedido e ir conferir perfil por perfil no SO-PT/EN. Não consigo ainda ver muito sentido, claro o link ficaria publico, mas não impede de uma pessoa de fora do site enviar um pedido por e-mail também, o META é publico também, creio eu. Seria interessante no formulário ter algo como "cole o link do teu perfil SOPT e SOEN".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o problema é esse justamente. Se o link for publico não tem triagem. Qualquer um chega no meta e pode sair respondendo à toa e perder tempo. Teria outras situações melhores, mas não com algo baseado em google docs, creio eu.

Comment: @Bacco mas se ele solicitar por e-mail não garante a triagem, pelo menos foi o que eu entendi.

Comment: O fato é que se for para fazer o que vcs estão sugerindo, não seria só o campo "email" mas também seria bom por campo para o ID do usuário do SOpt, e ID do usuário do SOzão. Teria outras situações melhores, mas não com algo baseado em google docs, creio eu. Ou então um belo aviso antes do link "Leia bem os requisitos, senão vai preencher à toa". E mesmo assim, sem nenhuma forma de contato não dá pra evitar que um malandro responda por você usando seus IDs. Não que pra mim qualquer das opções seja problema, só tou pondo mais pesos na balança pra "engordar" a discussão.

Comment: Para mim existem 2 cenários: se são necessárias 20 respostas, dá pra continuar na varinha de bambu; se forem necessárias centenas, tem de ser na rede arrastão e depois vc joga fora os pneus/sapatos/cascudos que vierem junto.
Além de que a validação/problemas do segundo caso (buscar o perfil em ambos sites) é a mesma que está sendo feita/existe agora.
Mas enfim, se o paciente se sente bem, não sou eu quem vai forçar o remédio; são só reflexões de quem já viu pesquisas dando muito errado.

Comment: Nem todos os usuários do SO-PT são brasileiros, e eu não estou a falar dos outros países onde também falam Português mas sim de Portugal, o original. Eu entendo que a diferença de população é grande, é só um bocado chato que em toda a Internet, Português, é praticamente sempre direcionado primeiro para os do Brasil. De qualquer forma, eu não estou aqui para discutir isso, quero é saber dos resultados quando saírem.

Comment: @user7393973 então, pensa-se primeiro no Brasil pq, entre outras coisas, o país é maior, tem mais habitantes... para você ter uma ideia, Portugal tem 10M de habitantes, o brasil tem 200M.. só São Paulo (a cidade) tem 16M... por isso que o Brasil acaba sendo a primeira coisa que sem pensa.. mas é claro que existem outros fatores...=).. e quanto aos resultados. Assim que a gente tiver eu divulgarei aqui. Mas vai demorar um pouco ainda =)... mas iremos divulgar =).

Comment: Eu até ajudaria, mas você tem que facilitar mais o acesso. Estou no trabalho e não posso ficar acessando email. Nos ajude a te ajudar.

Comment: @Washingtondacosta você poderia, por favor, me informar como eu posso fazer para lhe enviar um link? Você não pode acessar o email durante o trabalho, você tem alguma outra forma de comunicação? Skype? Só não trabalho com pombo correio pq é muito longe para atravessar o oceano hehehehe =p, brincando, mas me avisa qualquer coisa =)

Comment: Pessoal, eu atualizei o post para informar que vou encerrar o questionário na sexta (17/03/17). Quem puder responder antes eu ficaria muito grato. =)

Comment: Oi pessoal, passando só para atualizar vocês. Realizamos o sorteio do gift card e o ganhador foi o usuário Renan (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4808/renan?tab=profile). A única mudança em relação ao Gift Card foi que demos das Americanas ao invés da Saraiva por escolha do Renan. O resultado da pesquisa divulgaremos assim que possível, mas o artigo e a análise está 90% pronta.

Comment: @WeslleyTorres já o resultado?

Comment: @Maniero assim que o artigo for publicado eu posto os resultados aqui. Não posso publicar antes =/

Comment: Bom ver o retorno :D

Comment: Sugiro colocar a sua atualização com a publicação do artigo em uma resposta aqui nesta pergunta.