# Afinal... Pesquisas

Tags: debate, meta, pesquisa

Um tempo atrás eu abri o debate sobre a [divulgação de pesquisas acadêmicas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5724) no nosso Meta, depois de ser abordado pelo pessoal responsável por [uma pesquisa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5835) sobre a participação de pessoas com contas no SOen e SOpt.

O debate correu bem, e o resultado foi bastante favorável, com o único pedido de que, sempre que possível, os resultados dos estudos fossem divulgados para a comunidade.

Relendo o post eu percebo que ele abriu margem para diversas interpretações diferentes sobre o que estava sendo proposto (retrospecto é onisciente, né). E isso acabou gerando uma certa confusão a respeito de um post recente, também [anunciando uma pesquisa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5865).

Lendo os comentários eu percebo que algumas coisas que não ficaram claras no debate original:

1. **Não há obrigatoriedade crivo**
   O debate era sobre a permissão de anúncios no nosso Meta, independente da minha (ou de qualquer outro moderador ou gerente) aprovação ou crivo. A pergunta era se *vocês* queriam esse tipo de anúncio aqui, essencialmente dando permissão especial no escopo do Meta.

   Eu, obviamente, me coloco sempre à disposição de qualquer grupo de pesquisa para ajudar no que for possível. Mas não posso agir como palavra final sobre o que cabe ou não aqui.
2. **Não há obrigatoriedade de ser sobre o Stack Overflow**
   Aquela primeira pesquisa era sobre nossas comunidades, mas no post original não há menção sobre isso ser um requisito para uma pesquisa ser divulgada aqui. De maneira alguma isso significa que qualquer pesquisa sobre futebol, ou filmes do Harry Potter, ou etc, vão ser aceitas. Mas pesquisas que procurem a opinião de um conjunto de pessoas que trabalham com tecnologia tem tanto a ganhar com a participação de vocês quanto qualquer outra que seja sobre o Stack Overflow em sí.
3. **Você pode não gostar de uma pergunta, e ela ainda assim ficar no site**
   Como qualquer outra coisa que faz parte do escopo do site, as pesquisas não precisam agradar unanimamente - desde que não desagradem unanimamente. Se você acha que responder a pesquisa X não tem valor, siga em frente com a sua vida e deixe outras pessoas decidirem se querem ou não participar.

Dito isso, acho que essas coisas precisam também ir à debate. Não é bom aceitar algo assim, meio fora da norma, e não tentar estabelecer um mínimo de regras para a boa convivência, para garantir que a mudança seja benéfica de verdade ao site e à comunidade.

Então é uma boa hora de tentar debater quais um fundamento para o que vale, e o que não vale, quando o assunto é divulgação de pesquisas aqui. Sem tentar prever o futuro... Sem falar "se tiver uma pesquisa sobre mercado de trabalho, amanhã vão haver 40 sobre cerveja". Nada de tiro no escuro, ou argumento Mãe Dinah, por favor.

Vocês acham que a divulgação deve ser restrita a apenas um tipo de pesquisa?
As pesquisas precisam passar por algum tipo de pré-aprovação (caso a caso) antes de virem para o Meta?
Devem estar sujeitas à fechamento e avaliação mesmo sem estarem totalmente fora das regras?

Só vocês podem responder essas, e outras perguntas.

PS: No meio tempo, eu reabri o [anúncio mais recente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5865). Não faz sentido que esse post seja punido sem ter feito nada de errado explicitamente.

Comment: Por mim aceita-se tudo que é pesquisa, afinal se é para divulgar, divulga-se todas as pesquisas. Já responder ai fica ao critério de cada um. Afinal o meta esta parado e esta. Chega-lhe nas pesquisas!

Comment: A questão é aquela coisa de estar causando problema. Está? Me parece que não, então tá ok. Sobre o Harry Potter estava no escopo sempre aqui no meta, mas ele não tem mais conta, então agora não é mais :P Essa última pesquisa postada era tão ruim que eu não acho que ela merecia nenhuma relevância. Por isso que [eu falei no gato](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5725/101) (não o nosso, o de  Schrödinger mesmo). Eu acho que há casos e casos. É o mesmo q fazemos no site, algo pode estar no escopo, mas se a qualidade é ruim, tem que fechar, ou fazer algo pra deixar claro que aquilo ñ é adequado

Comment: Eu sou contra divulgação de pesquisas aqui e em qualquer lugar... Qualquer pesquisa que é feita por questionário na internet sofre do problema de [viés de não-resposta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-response_bias), ou [viés de participação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participation_bias), tirando o [viés de seleção](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias). Isso afeta, e muito, as conclusões das pesquisas acadêmicas. Se for só para aprendizado, para o TCC, ou porque algum professor pediu, acho que não deveria ser divulgado aqui...

Answer (score 10):

No primeiro post onde o Gabe pediu opiniões sobre permitir pesquisas no SO-pt, eu opinei com indiferença dizendo que não me posicionaria contra, desde que não fossem abusivas, mas que também não participaria de nenhuma pesquisa.

Depois de um tempo, confesso que fiquei surpreso ao ver a primeira pesquisa.

A surpresa foi negativa pois eu imaginava que as pesquisas seriam bem formatadas e dentro das páginas do SO-pt. SQN (só que não).

Fiquei surpreso em ver que eram meras postagens aqui no meta que levam a sites terceiros. Eu imaginava algo como uma enquete pública integrada ao site principal e não somente mais uma postagem no meta. Seria algo assim:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>   
> <sub>A imagem é ilustrativa</sub>

Eu imaginava algo mais profissional, bem elaborado e controlado pelo SO-pt. Como eu disse que não participaria, não acompanhei nenhuma das pesquisas e nem sei quantas aconteceram. Mas analisando essa específica que foi altamente negativada [Pesquisa de opinião sobre satisfação e realidade no setor de TI](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5865), parece ser algo disperso, sem controle por parte do SO-pt e pior que isso são anúncios que nada agregam ao escopo do site nem mesmo ao Meta.

Ainda falando dessa pesquisa negativada, o AP sequer provê um feedback aos comentários. Fica uma impressão estranha, uma coisa esquisita. Ignorando a todos. Alguém pode avisá-lo que aqui nós latimos mas não mordemos. rsr. Ele pode prover um feedback e procurar melhorar e negociar com a comunidade. Adotar uma postura profissional.

Se quer colaboração de alguém e ignora essa pessoa, como que obterá cooperação?

Afinal, responder 29 questões requer tempo.

Preferi não me intrometer logo na primeira pesquisa pois optei por não participar. Mas como abriu esse debate, achei o momento oportuno.

**Resumindo**, esse problema da pesquisa refutada é consequência de falta de gestão, timing e ambiente adequado. Expõe o AP a algo negativo quando os usuários nagativam. Por isso, acredito que seria melhor num formato como na ilustração acima, pois cria uma "capa de proteção".
Claro que isso tem custo em desenvolver um sistema para controlar e ter pessoas gerenciando. Mas seria um formato mais seguro, não misturando com as perguntas técnicas do escopo do site, não expondo o autor ou detentor da pesquisa diretamente e não incomodando ninguém.

Tenho outro assunto pertinente sob o ponto de vista comercial, mas prefiro não expressar no momento.

Answer (score 4):

> Vocês acham que a divulgação deve ser restrita a apenas um tipo de pesquisa?

Não. Salvo que tenha que estar dentro do escopo de programação, ou no minimo sobre TI, levamos em conta aqui que quem trabalha com programação, provavelmente esta por dentro sobre assuntos voltados a TI.

Aí vai um outro ponto, pergunta de satisfação de tecnologia por exemplo, alguém que esteja fazendo uma monografia sobre tudo o que há de ruim em uma linguagem de programação, e que queira uma opinião sincera de uma comunidade que trabalha com isso.

Aí ele elabora perguntas sobre características de duas linguagens por exemplo, e monta aqueles tipos de perguntas em que devemos responder aonde, em quais características, uma leva vantagem em cima da outra, para conseguir levantar dados para elaborar a dissertação.

Seria cabível aqui?

A meu ver **sim**, seria baseado em opiniões, mas afinal essa seria a intenção da pesquisa. A opinião de usuários de determinadas tecnologias, aonde o único requisito para responder a pesquisa seria que quem respondeu conhecesse o mínimo possível das tecnologias. Claro que quem elaborou o questionário também deve levar em consideração respostas dadas sem um pingo de conhecimento sobre o assunto, isso meio que foge do controle, seria da boa fê de quem respondeu.

> As pesquisas precisam passar por algum tipo de pré-aprovação (caso a caso) antes de virem para o Meta?

Com certeza! Mesmo que seja somente um esboço do questionário, um escopo prévio das perguntas, para que **possamos** avaliar se estão adequadas, veja que na pergunta que gerou a confusão o @VictorStafusa apontou vários erros que meio que tiram toda legitimidade de um estudo científico, além de ficar bem complicado responder com imparcialidade em algumas perguntas.

Geralmente em um estudo científico, o cientista tem um grupo de controle (grupo de indivíduos que num experimento não recebem qualquer tratamento especial, a fim de servir como referência-padrão às variáveis a que se submete o grupo experimental) ao qual já submeteu as perguntas, eles que devem indicar os pontos equivocados da pesquisa, aqui somos o grupo experimental. Se o pesquisador não fizer a lição de casa e a pesquisa estiver em outros termos, **porca**, não somos nos que devemos fazer a lição de casa pra ele e nesses casos a pequisa deve sim ser fechada.

Agora seria preciso decidir **quem** e/ou **aonde** aprovaríamos a pesquisa.

Mesmo pesquisas boas podem conter erros de concordância e coerência entre outros e apontar quais são esses erros sempre é bem-vindo, contanto que o elaborador da pesquisa os corrija (se possível, antes de lançar a versão oficial, para que não obtenha dados equivocados, e não seja necessário uma nova resposta do pesquisado). Isso também acaba criando muita burocracia, mas novamente, não somos nós que devemos fazer a lição de casa pra ele. Estando assim, ele ciente de que há problemas na pesquisa, e que obter resultados inválidos fica por sua própria conta e risco.

No meu ponto de vista, a própria comunidade poderia fazer isso, com comentários apontando os possíveis erros, votos para fechar, negativando ou simplesmente ignorando.

> Devem estar sujeitas à fechamento e avaliação mesmo sem estarem totalmente fora das regras?

Para mim, depende de como a pesquisa foi elaborada, e qual o propósito. Alguns tipos de pesquisas, poderiam caber aqui [stackUnderflow](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackunderflow/)

Por que não? Poderia montar um tópico só aqui de pesquisas acadêmicas que vincule a pesquisa lá, não sei, é uma sugestão.

Quem quiser criar uma pesquisa, poderia elaborar a pesquisa assim como o rapaz [fez](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5865/pesquisa-de-opini%C3%A3o-sobre-satisfa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-realidade-no-setor-de-ti), jogar no meta, e aguardar a aprovação da comunidade ou não. Não sei direito como ocorreu com a [primeira pesquisa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5835/question%C3%A1rio-survey-usu%C3%A1rios-stackoverfow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-e-ingl%C3%AAs), mas me parece que ela estava bem mais madura. Tinha problemas, mas ainda assim não tantos quanto a segunda, daí o porquê de ter havido aprovação na primeira, e não na segunda.

Answer (score -2):

Eu gosto de responder pesquisas, por mim eu responderia sem problemas.