# Pesquisa - Por que as pessoas buscam trabalhar ou não na área de TI?

Tags: debate, estudo-científico

Olá. Meu nome é Ana. Estou fazendo um TCC para a minha pós-graduação em Educação, Diversidade e Inclusão Social. O meu tema é "**A inclusão da mulher no mundo da tecnologia da informação**".

Falei com o Gabe antes por e-mail, e após algumas orientações, ele me disse que apoia a pesquisa e que acredita ser pertinente de ser postado aqui.

O objetivo do meu trabalho é explorar quais são as razões que levam a haver poucas mulheres atuando nas áreas de TI. Apesar disso, eu gostaria de receber **respostas tanto de homens quanto de mulheres** para poder traçar diferenças culturais, sociais, psicológicas e comportamentais.

As respostas a este questionário são anônimas. Os dados coletados serão divulgados publicamente no Google Drive e também aqui no meta. Também publicarei o meu TCC com os resultados no Google Drive.

O tempo estimado de resposta é de 10 a 20 minutos. A pesquisa vai ficar disponível durante todo o mês de julho, mas gostaria que quem pudesse, respondesse o quanto antes para não acabar esquecendo.

Informações como faixa salarial, etnia e gênero são coletadas para que diferenças culturais e sociais sejam evidenciadas. Elas não tem como propósito identificar ninguém.

Por fim, agradeço a todos que quiserem compartilhar o link desta pesquisa em suas redes sociais. Mesmo aquele(a)s que não trabalham e/ou não querem trabalhar com TI também podem responder à pesquisa, o que é útil para evidenciar diferenças sociais, psicológicas, culturais e comportamentais existentes entre as pessoas que são da área de TI em comparação com as que não são.

Quem quiser mais detalhes pode entrar em contato comigo por e-mail (`amflemes@gmail.com`).

Agradeço a colaboração de todos.

Link para a pesquisa: https://goo.gl/forms/wgEykQYNTV8565f12

Comment: Respondi a pesquisa sua.

Comment: Como esta pesquisa passou pela nossa moderação, entendo que estamos dando um respiro às nossas *meta-questões*, e cedendo o espaço para um assunto totalmente pertinente à nossa área e ao momento atual que vivemos - acho que vale dar uma força! +1 :)

Comment: Um video que toca no assunto - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-6usiN4uoA

Comment: @BrunoCosta based mom to the rescue

Comment: Estou respondendo, mas uma coisa me incomodou. Na pergunta 9 deveria ter um 'discordo'. Porque não é que eu 'não sei' ou 'não me incomodo' é que eu discordo que a afirmação seja verdadeira.

Answer (score 4):

### Porque não vou participar/Porque não sou a favor

Vou ser sincero, não sou a favor deste tipo de pesquisa, pois assim como as anteriores (umas 2 que houveram antes), os resultados não foram divulgados e não teve utilidade para a comunidade, ou seja pode ajudar as pessoas que estão fazendo TCC e etc, mas não ajuda mais ninguém, então não tem utilidade de fato.

O meu intuito não é barrar as pesquisas, muito pelo contrário, é colocar ordem, definir um *"critério"* ou maneira ou até processo para que possa ser útil, tanto ao AP quanto a comunidade.

Não é um problema pessoal com essa pergunta e nem com as outras, o problema e nem é culpa dos autores da pergunta, o problema é um comportamento comum das pessoas, formulei algo para debatermos:

- [Que tal definirmos um padrão minimo para o uso da tag [estudo-científico]?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6144/3635)

### Porque acredito que exista ainda diferenças (sobre a pesquisa)

> Apesar de não participar preciso deixar algo sobre o assunto.

Sinceramente eu tenho uma opinião muito pessoal, eu já debati com dois usuários que tinham uma visão um tanto quanto *sexista* (não é por mal), não eram totalmente erradas, ainda sim **eu acredito** (opinião apenas) que cada ser humano seja dotado de um interesse próprio, as pessoas "geralmente" acreditam no argumento que: *mulheres são de humanas, homens de exatas*, mas eu acho isto **extremamente relativo**, ao meu ver a área de TI é uma área estressante, conheço homens e mulheres que desistiram, para falar a verdade conheci alguns alunos do ano de 2013 na Fatec, começaram com ~58 alunos, no ultimo ano restavam apenas 5, inclusive os 5 foram os que se formaram, entre os 53 que desistiram a maioria era homem.

"O que você quer dizer com isto?" você deve ter se perguntado, eu simplesmente quero dizer que TI é uma área muito nova, explorada somente por algumas pessoas, é uma área para a maioria igual a estudar talvez aramaico, quase ninguém sabe, pergunte a sua mãe e a seu pai, ou a outra pessoa que não seja da área se ela tem noção de quem criou um aplicativo simples para celular que ela usa, tenho certeza que na mente das pessoas todos Apps são criados por grandes empresas e pessoas formadas.

Então TI é uma área bem evoluída, mas só esta começando a se tornar comum como profissão agora, mesmo que muitas empresas usassem ainda sim mesmo o seu chefe ou patrão não entendem o que você é ou o que você como TI representa. Claro que é muito **relativo**, tem empresas que são diferentes, ainda sim a maior parte do mundo não enxerga isto.

Eu vou citar um exemplo (me critiquem a vontade), mas quem já viu a série britânica [***IT crowd***](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_IT_Crowd) não pode negar (mesmo que seja ficção) as coisas na área são bem assim, o TI da empresa ficava no primeiro andar (ou sub-solo) não lembro e eram praticamente esquecidos e não estou falando dos personagens, mas sim de como eram tratados pelos demais, a questão é como o TI é visto, as pessoas simplesmente nem sabem quais as funções, eu mesmo já recebi ordens para concertar ventilador, cafeteira, aparelho de telefone, entre outras coisas um tanto quanto absurdas.

Eu não culpo as pessoas, é uma área ainda estranha para a maioria mesmo quem trabalha com TI, alguns realmente nem sabem o que estão fazendo ali direito ou são limitados a uma coisa bem mais simplória (conheço muita gente que finge saber as coisas, inclusive tive que trabalhar com um).

**Para concluir**, é tudo muito relativo e as pessoas ainda desconhecem o que é TI, independente de ser homem ou mulher e mesmo alguns da própria área não entendem bem o que estão fazendo.

### Resumo

Formulei esta resposta pois para mim a pesquisa vai ser como as outras que houveram, não vai servir em nada para a comunidade, então prefiro deixar como resposta, para que discordem ou concordem do meu ponto de vista.

Comment: O TCC de hoje pode ser a tese de amanhã. A AP pode chegar a conclusões relevantes sobre o tema, e beneficiar a comunidade da mesma maneira que o  SO faz. Apoio à ciência é fundamental.

Comment: @OnoSendai Eu concordo, mas isso é o que esperamos, no entanto nem sempre ocorre, a minha discordância é porque geralmente não divulgam e geralmente só servem como trabalho mesmo, nota e etc. Falo isto devido a outros que já passaram aqui e uma série de mesma situações em grupos do facebook sobre "teses", venho peço passo na matéria e depois esqueço de divulgar para quem tanto me apoiou. Eu apoio totalmente a ciência, a minha discordância é com outra coisa.

Comment: Se os autores das das pesquisas passadas não divulgaram seus resultados a falta está neles e não no processo. Além disso, 3 casos é um *sampling* muito baixo. =)

Comment: @OnoSendai pra mim esta sim no processo, o que quero dizer é que para mim eu acredito que o processo deve ter um *"padrão minimo para ser feito aqui"*, a maior parte que chegam aqui com estas pesquisas serão só interessados em passar em seu TCC, temos que organizar a coisa desde o começo para que ela seja minimamente proveitosa ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vou descordar um pouco de vc :D Não é só porque algumas pessoas que fazem pesquisas e acaba não divulgando o resultado, deixando outras pessoas na mão, que significa que o AP vai nos deixar na mão. Acho q vc generalizou um pouco, vamos dar uma chance para o AP e descobrir o que pode sair de bom dessa pesquisa. Afinal de contas, o AP deixou o e-mail dela lá, então sem dúvida, vamos cobrar pelo resultado da pesquisa =)

Comment: @gato concordo contigo também, mas o meu intuito não é nem de longe barrar as pesquisas, a minha intenção é botar ordem no barraco e definir um padrão minimo para que se possa fazer a pesquisa, entende?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entendo, tem que ter padrão e ordem sim, senão as pessoas vão fazer nas coxas, e ao invés de estarem fazendo ciência ou contribuindo com o estudo cientifico, irá gerar um efeito ruim.

Comment: @gato Perfeitamente, da maneira que esta hoje só vai sair isto mesmo nas coxas, só se o AP tiver muito boa vontade é que vai colaborar de volta, mas quem anda aparecendo aqui são pessoas interessadas em passar no seus TCCs, isso virou uma porta para trabalho de faculdade, eu só vi gente que nem sabe o que é o site direito participando, se tiver uma organização ou regra minima então irei apoiar **`110%`** essas pesquisas :D

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento concordo, vamos esperar para vê. Se isso ficar se repetindo muito, vamos dar um jeito de mostrar para essas pessoas que não estamos aqui só para ajudar ela a concluir o TCC e nada de bom é extraído da pesquisa. Eu também não gosto que as pessoas vem aqui pede para os membros participar da pesquisa e depois some e nem divulga os resultados e a conclusão da pesquisa. Isso é 100% egoismo, e egoismo não faz ciência.

Comment: Acho que não temos muito o que esperar, no máximo uma pessoa ou outra irá divulgar, enquanto não for um "norma" ninguém vai ligar mesmo, se for norma e seguir um padrão bem simplório mas bem definido, então sim teremos algo proveitoso, as pessoas são assim, se for esperar boa vontade não terá muita coisa, só estaremos ajudando algumas pessoas a fazerem seus "trabalhos de casa", eu nem estou falando só desses que vieram pedir isto, mas sim do comportamento comum esperado. Se é para abrir uma porta não seria melhor ao menos colocar um porteiro?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento existe alguma pergunta no meta que ao menos orienta os usuários em relação as normas a respeito de pesquisas e trabalhos acadêmicos?

Comment: @gato pois é, não existe, tem um debate, mas nada definido, só um punhado de opiniões de como deve ocorrer ou algo como "eu apoio" e "eu não apoio", mas nada que defina como deveria ocorrer: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5724/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento 1) Se faltam regras claras sobre pesquisas realizadas com membros do SOpt, bem, digo que o meta serve exatamente para isso. Se isso até hoje tem sido feito "nas coxas", é porque não foi debatido o suficiente no meta. 2) Como o OnoSendai disse, o *sampling* até aqui foi pequeno, não dá para generalizar. Além disso, não tenho como me responsabilizar pelo que os outros (não) fizeram, sabe-se lá por qual razão.

Comment: 3) Quanto a presença de um "porteiro", eu falei com o Gabe antes por meio de e-mail e pelo menos no caso de uma das pesquisas anteriores, o interessado também o fez, então já temos um porteiro. 4) Quanto a "*organizar as coisas*" minimamente, concordo. Foi por isso que revisei o questionário um monte de vezes antes de publicá-lo e pedi a opinião do Gabe antes.

Comment: 5) Você poderia ver isso como "só mais um TCC". E se eu não quisesse publicar os resultados, de fato, não seria mais do que isso. Entretanto, o objetivo aqui é estudar um problema real que afeta toda a área de TI, e por consequência a comunidade do SOpt também, pois como o Gabe mesmo me disse e todos daqui sabemos muito bem, esse site é majoritariamente masculino. Assim sendo, o problema da inclusão da mulher, por mais batido e clichê que possa parecer, existe e é forte na TI, mas há poucas pesquisas que apontam as causas disso (e sim, eu já pesquisei e continuo pesquisando isso bastante).

Comment: @AninhaFerreira Não é algo pessoal contigo, então recomendo que não se estresse, estou falando do comportamento normal do ser humano, não precisa se sentir atacada ;) não é nada pessoal contigo, o problema é outra coisa, se não consegui deixar claro aqui então espero que nesta tenha ficado mais claro: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6144/3635, sobre estudos do sexo e influencias eu tentei deixar minha opinião, se lhe foi util não sei, eu tentei colaborar.

Comment: @AninhaFerreira Com eu disse, se tiver ordem e tiver o porteiro eu vou apoiar 110% as pesquisas e participar de todas possíveis, caso contrario estou solicitando apoio da comunidade para barrarmos provisoriamente, não estou censurando tua pergunta, estou apenas tentando organizar o site. Assim que estiver organizado então abriríamos espaço novamente para este tipo de pesquisa. Obrigado por compreender ;)