# Que tal definirmos um padrão minimo para o uso da tag [estudo-científico]?

Tags: debate, tag-específica, estudo-científico

Me deparei com certa aceitação sobre as perguntas, eu tentei me expressar sobre o assunto em [estudo-científico](/questions/tagged/estudo-cient%c3%adfico), mas logo notei que não consegui mostrar da melhor maneira o meu ponto de vista, quero dizer, eu não sou contra estudos científicos, muito pelo contrário, no entanto da maneira que está é uma porta aberta sem porteiro.

Se colocarmos uma regra/padrão minimo a ser seguido eu irei apoiar **110%** e participarei de todos que forem possíveis, mas da maneira que esta a comunidade só esta servindo para ajudar as pessoas com seus trabalhos de TCC, até pode ser que alguém diga que qualquer estudo servirá para teses futuras, se for um bom estudo, mas eu vou ser sincero se colocar um pouco mais de ordem tenho certeza que um mesmo estudo servirá para várias possíveis teses ao invés de uma única tese (a feita pelo autor da pergunta).

Agora se os resultados forem talvez abertos e usar uma ferramenta que obrigue a deixar os resultados abertos, mesmo que os participantes sejam anônimos diferentes pessoas poderão usar os resultados para estudos próprios e então de um mero trabalho de TCC teremos mais de uma pessoa fazendo uso dos dados.

O que acham? Minha sugestão é definir na Wiki da tag [estudo-científico](/questions/tagged/estudo-cient%c3%adfico) as "regras básicas" e a possivel ferramenta (ainda não pensei em nenhuma) para divulgação dos dados.

Comment: Relacionada: [Afinal… Pesquisas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5874/91)

Comment: Gostei muito da ideia de deixar os resultados aberto para o publico, acredito que o stackoverflow sempre promoveu a utilização de seus recursos para quem tiver os mesmos problemas futuramente, e isso seria mais uma porta aberta para isso.

Comment: Sou a favor disto. E a questão de divulgar os resultados é muito importante, até porque, a Ciência não deve ser feita em segredo ;)

Comment: Eu acho muita discussão pra pouca coisa :D

Comment: @bigown no momento sim, mas então uma pessoa faz um TCC espalha para outros, "faz uma consulta lá no meta do sopt", em seguida (gradativamente/bola de neve) começa aparecer várias pessoas com pequisas meia-boca sem utilidade de verdade para a comunidade. Não é questão de resolver um problema atual. Creio que prevenir seja melhor que remediar, não? Outra, não é uma discussão para resolver de imediato, quem tem tempo livre venha e opine, só deixei a discussão em aberto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sobre o seu receio: 1. Não há qualquer evidência de que isso está acontecendo. 2. Qualquer regra a respeito de pesquisas pode ser instaurada a qualquer momento, efetivamente resolvendo o problema imediatamente. Sou totalmente a favor da discussão a respeito de que tipos de pesquisas/questionários vocês se dispõem ou se sentem confortáveis a responder, mas o argumento de que "é melhor prevenir do que remediar" vai de encontro a toda filosofia do Stack.

Comment: @Gabe só estou tentando fazer a coisa ser proveitosa, talvez eu esteja enganado, talvez não, só levantei um questionamento e nada mais.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu não me coloquei contrário ao seu questionamento, nem botei em cheque o quão proveitosa é a discussão. Me refiro apenas ao seu comentário para o bigown. Como eu falei, a aceitação de que tipo de questionários são permitidos aqui é prerrogativa da comunidade, o que não significa que toda motivação por trás de qualquer limitação seja válida.

Comment: @Gabe eu só expliquei o motivo de levantar o questionamento, se vai ser um problema futuro ou não eu não sei, acho que ninguém sabe, não estou aqui pra censurar ninguém e nem nada, é só preocupação pela saúde do site, que sempre tive, mas que seja vou evitar estes tipos de perguntas e discussões aqui, talvez eu pense realmente diferente da maioria, talvez eu veja problemas aonde ninguém enxerga, talvez eu acredite em coisas que nunca irão ocorrer. Vou deixar o "fluxo" correr livre sem me intrometer mais em nada e nem em nenhum possivel problema qualquer que eu notar.